# Hide or replace text using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On [this page](https://philadelphiamusicfestival.org/wordpress/our-faculty/) you can see the text "0here" below the breadcrumb.

That text is coming from a theme I do not even have installed. I suspect it's coming from the database because I duplicated the old DB to build the new site.

Anyway, I'm trying to hide/delete/replace the "0here" or else it will appear on every page.

I'm trying...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(':contains("0here")').html().replace("0here", "");
});
</script>
```

But not working. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to write the HTML back again, but this is really not a very good idea, remove the root of the problem instead.

Comment: Yes as adeneo says you need to solve the actual problem than a workaround.. Even if what you are trying is achieved it's still a HUGE performance loss. You are searching the entire HTML and redrawing the entire HTML which is very costly. May be other better way would be to clean up the data in server code while passing it to HTML

Comment: Use `$("#breadcrumbs").prop("nextSibling", "")`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo and Reddy for encouraging me to keep looking for the root of the problem. I followed your advice, found it, and fixed it. Turns out the text was coming from an included child template, not the parent template I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try only replace. I dont think you need html. it works over all selector.

```
//use one of them
jQuery(':contains("0here")').replace("0here", "");
jQuery(':contains("0here")').html("");
jQuery(':contains("0here")').val(""); //if input or text area
```

Comment: First one: replace is not a function(…)
Second one: no html displays at all
Third one: "0here" still displays